# strange bundler error: tar_input.rb:49:in `initialize': not in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) on bundle pack

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

i am getting a strange bundler error when running

```
bundle pack
```

with bundler 0.9.12

any ideas? (see pastie for a better formatted code: http://pastie.org/881328 )

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:49:in `initialize': not in gzip format (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:49:in `new'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:49:in `initialize'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:63:in `each'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:54:in `loop'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:54:in `each'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:32:in `initialize'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:17:in `new'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package/tar_input.rb:17:in `open'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/package.rb:55:in `open'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/format.rb:63:in `from_io'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/format.rb:51:in `from_file_by_path'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/format.rb:50:in `open'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/format.rb:50:in `from_file_by_path'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:115:in `specs'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:114:in `each'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/source.rb:114:in `specs'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:32:in `from_cached_specs'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:23:in `application_cached_gems'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:15:in `cached_gems'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:5:in `build'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:14:in `cached_gems'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/environment.rb:15:in `index'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/index.rb:5:in `build'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/environment.rb:13:in `index'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `specs'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:130:in `details'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:119:in `write_yml_lock'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `lock'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:89:in `lock'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/cli.rb:131:in `package'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:33:in `send'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:33:in `run'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:109
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:116:in `call'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:116:in `invoke'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:137:in `start'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:378:in `start'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:124:in `start'
  from /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-0.9.12/bin/bundle:11
  from /opt/REE/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
  from /opt/REE/bin/bundle:19
```

Comment: Also happens to me, and it's elusive in my case, repeated runs may start the app successfully

Answer (score 14, accepted):

to answer my own question:

the fix was to delete all the contents from

```
vendor/cache
```

after that it worked.

clearly a bundler bug.

Answer (score 21):

I was having similar problem with bundle upate (bundler 1.0).
I am using rvm with gemset for my application.

Solution was to remove:

~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@gemset-name/cache

Comment: Ugh, didn't work for me. I was really hoping it would. Still researching here…

Comment: This worked for me. It's worth noting that after doing this, I had to run bundle install on all of my apps and gems using bundler.

Comment: For any Googlers coming this way: it can also mean your gem source is down or inaccessible. I hit this problem when trying to pull gems down from my company's repo without being connected to VPN.

Answer (score 7):

Allegedly, the original issue is fixed with Bundler 1.0.x, but I still had the same error message (using 1.0.3).  I removed all `cache` folders, including in RVM directories, as outlined in the other answers here -- no dice.

It turns out you'll *also* get this error if Bundler can't resolve one of your sources (i.e., those returned by `$ gem sources`).  Even if you list multiple sources, it will ping all of them, and if *any* source is bad, it will crash with this nondescript `'initialize': not in gzip format` error.

As described in [this ticket](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=25816&group_id=126&atid=575), that can be because of something like an inaccessible VPM or local network source, but I actually ran into the problem due to my company's firewall blocking rubygems.org.

Just submitting this answer as *another* possible solution to clear up this vague error message.

Answer (score 4):

just happened to me with bundler 0.9.26 and rails3 beta4. launched

```
bundle package
```

now it works. but if I remove vendor/cache the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same thing, removed /bundler_gems/cache

Answer (score 2):

Even though I'm running Bundler 1.0.0, I still hit this error.  `bundle install` didn't work, but running `bundle package` did.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rf vendor/cache`

`bundle package`

`bundle install`

`bundle lock`

It's a bit annoying... I don't know why I can't do `bundle install --relock`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Capistrano with Bundler's `require 'bundler/capistrano'`, the cache directory is at `shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/cache`.

Answer (score 0):

All traces of this error went away when I upgraded to Bundler 1.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue in a rails 3.1 app by deleting the archived gem files:

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.0.17
$ rm -f vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/cache/*.gem
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when deploying, but didn't want to remove `vendor/cache` from git.

Instead, I ended up doing this:

```
# deploy.rb
namespace :bundle do
  desc "Removes vendor/cache when NO_GEM_CACHE=1 is set. Resolves Zlib::GzipFile::Error (not in gzip format)."
  task :remove_cache do
    run "rm -fr #{release_path}/vendor/cache" if ENV['NO_GEM_CACHE'] == '1'
  end
end
before :'bundle:install', :'bundle:remove_cache'
```

Whenever this error crops up simply:

```
cap deploy NO_GEM_CACHE=1
```